# Delete substring from file to end of line

Tags: regex, powershell, wildcard

Consider the file dummy.txt, as follows:

```
SomeMessage: "BLABLABLA Value 'V1' of attribute 'CLR', Additional Information: 'Sometext'."
SomeMessage: "BLABLABLA Value 'W2' of attribute 'HGT', Additional Information: 'Sometextmore'."
SomeMessage: "BLABLABLA Value 'X3' of attribute 'SND', Additional Information: 'EvenSomeBiggerBulk'."
```

How can I delete each substring from each line beginning with `", Additional Information"` up to the end of the line? So that I get the following result:

```
SomeMessage: "BLABLABLA Value 'V1' of attribute 'CLR'
SomeMessage: "BLABLABLA Value 'W2' of attribute 'HGT'
SomeMessage: "BLABLABLA Value 'X3' of attribute 'SND'
```

I tried:

```
(Get-Content dummy.txt).Replace(', Additional*." ', '') | Set-Content temp.txt
```

But this left the file unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost correct

```
(Get-Content dummy.txt) -replace ", Additional.*" | Set-Content temp.txt
```

Instead of the .NET String method `.Replace()` this uses the PowerShell operator `-replace`.

The .NET method accepts two strings, `oldValue` and `newValue` and does not use regular expressions. It can only replace exact matches.

The PowerShell operator also accepts two strings, but it uses regular expressions. The `newValue` string is optional if you just want to remove the matches.

Comment: `*.` ? do you mean `.*` ? :)

Comment: Thank you. The following solution works fine: 
<pre>
`(Get-Content dummy.txt) -replace ", Additional.*" | Set-Content temp.txt` <\pre> 
Howerver, can someone explain why it ist `.*` instead of `*.`

Comment: @SamNorton in regex `.` is 'any character', and `*` means 'repeat the previous char zero or more times' so your `Additional*.` would actually be any number of the letter `l` repeated, followed by any one char, hopefully that explains it.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for:

`(Get-Content dummy.txt) -replace (",\sAdditional.*", "") > temp.txt`

I like the `>` redirector better (pipe would work fine too).  I have improved the `regex` to match what you are searching for.

Comment: @tukan `,` is not a special character in regex, there is no need to escape it. `\s` is not better than a space, especially since the OP's file only has a space. Where is the regex improvement you speak of?

Comment: @Tomalak you are right about the `,` - will fix it. `\s` is an equivalent for a space that is also true.  The improvement is visual and not functional.  If you have complex regexp, it is easier to spot `\s` than ` `

Comment: But when you do a non-regex replace, you'd have to use a regular space in the search string and it would be very easy to spot. It's not harder to spot in a regex. :) It's a matter of preference, really.

Comment: @Tomalak it is that is totally true.  Since I did some complex regexp I just have this habit and it never bit me back :), so I call it improvement.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.